# Query works in MySQL but I get 'Query was empty' in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is part of a simple password manager. I get an error saying the Query is empty yet the query works just fine in MySQL. (The 1 and the test value were originally variables I just changed them to values as part of my troubleshooting). I am also aware that the column names user and password may be problematic, but I added ` around them. What else could be wrong with that code?

```
$change_pass_query = "UPDATE `user` SET `password` = PASSWORD('test') WHERE id = 1";
$change_pass_result = mysql_query($change_pass_query) or die('Error. Change Password Query failed: '. mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your SQL like this:

```
UPDATE `user` SET `password` = 'test' WHERE `id` = 1
```

Comment: how is this different than the OP's, other than removing the [`PASSWORD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function?

Comment: It gives the same error. I actually tried that too earlier just to eliminate the chance that it had to do with the PASSWORD() function.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Notice the warning at the top of that page. Nobody uses `mysql_query` or any plain `mysql` functions. Research `mysqli`/`mysqli_query`, and PDO.

Here's how you could do this with PDO:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb","username","password");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `user` SET `password` = PASSWORD(:password) WHERE id = :id");
$result = $stmt->execute(array(':password' => "test",':id' => 1));
if (!$result) die('Error. Change Password Query failed: '. mysql_error());
```

Here's some documentation on PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I know. I use PDO mostly, but I can't afford to rewrite this existing software and it is in an intranet where I find mysql functions are acceptable for now until I do have time to change everything to PDO.

Still, mysql should work and I don't think it is the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up renaming all tables and fields so that I didn't use any reserved words, as I thought that the issue might be that. The problem still happened. I then copied my code to a different PHP box, et voila, the code works just fine. I'll have to put it down to an issue with the PHP version/installation on the older box and move on. There is nothing wrong with the code.